# Increasing variable gradually in Unity, the variable keeps reverting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a 2d game in Unity, it is an endless level runner game. I am trying to increase the speed of the moving objects over time, however the speed keeps reverting. I have tried numerous different ways of changing this code but I cannot seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public class pipeMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;
    float targetSpeed = 12f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("Speed: " + speed);
        if (speed < targetSpeed)
        {
            speed += 2f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm seeing in my log:

```
Speed: 7.599998
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
pipeMove:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/pipeMove.cs:13)

Speed: 12.00009
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
pipeMove:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/pipeMove.cs:13)

Speed: 12.00009
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
pipeMove:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/pipeMove.cs:13)

Speed: 11.62008
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
pipeMove:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/pipeMove.cs:13)

Speed: 9.620035
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
pipeMove:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/pipeMove.cs:13)

Speed: 7.619998
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
pipeMove:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/pipeMove.cs:13)

Speed: 12.00009
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
pipeMove:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/pipeMove.cs:13)
```

I am not sure what is making the speed increase and decrease rather than just increase.

Comment: Not sure what's going on with that speed variable, but when using FixedUpdate it's best to pair it with Time.fixedDeltaTime instead of Time.deltaTime

Comment: Are you sure nothing is changing the value of `speed`? I have just run this locally and it behaves as expected (increases until reach 12). Try changing `speed` to private maybe to be sure nothing else is modifying it.

Comment: other instantiated objects with the same script on?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
using UnityEngine;
     
     public class pipeMove : MonoBehaviour
     {
         private float speed  = 6f;
         private float targetSpeed = 12f;
         
         void Update ()
         {
             if (speed < targetSpeed)
                 speed += 2f * Time.deltaTime;
         }
     }
```

From [Unity answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1300584/how-do-i-increase-a-speed-variable-over-time.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that, I have the same issue. Thank you though.

Comment: Is there something else that influences your variable `speed`? It is marked public so something else can change it. Also I fail to see how this answer is any different from OPs code. What does this add?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to make it a local Variable just so nothing can edit it outside the FixedUpdate.

```
public class pipeMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float speed = 6f;
        float targetSpeed = 12f;

        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("Speed: " + speed);
        if (speed < targetSpeed)
        {
            speed += 2f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```